# Архитектура авторизации в приложении

Tags: c#, wcf

Мое приложение авторизовываться с помощью одного метода Authorize в сервисе wcf. Аргумент ы метода - логин, пароль, параметры машины пользователя (processorId и IP) и bool startup. При авторизации сравнивается логин и пароль из базы данных. Если startup == true, то тогда сравнивается не пароль, а ProcessorId сессии (с помощью этого я реализовал сохранение сессии, чтобы не надо было каждый раз вводить пароль). Если узнать ProcessorId то в сервис можно будет авторизоваться любому человеку, это дыра в безопасности :с Как можно эту дыру залатать? Переделать способ сохранения сессии, или часть метода?

Comment: используйте токен аутентификации

Comment: Надо по большому счету писать самому, основываясь на RSA и персональных сертификатах, тогда все эти проблемы уйдут сами собой, как и многие другие, которые вы пока ещё не обнаружили :)

Comment: И по IP привязываться ненадёжно, хоть и удобно, подмена не так уж и сложна в реализации. IP удобно рассматривать как фактор, например с точки зрения ASN и/или Geo данных, обычно пользователи не меняют хаотично место физического прибывания :)

Comment: @NewView Да, я использую айпи только для статистики

Comment: @NewView И можно поподробнее про RSA и персональные сертификаты

Comment: Авторизация по https с помощью персональных сертификатов, использовать данный метод можно и без https, подписывать что то, персональным сертификатом (данные). Поищите например 'nginx персональные сертификаты', слишком объемная тема для комментария.

Comment: @NewView Мне вот что в своём коде не нравится, можно авторизоваться без пароля, а по processorid

Comment: Авторизоваться надо по персональному сертификату, с привязкой к железу. Гарантия почти 100%